# Creating handlers in for elements in imported js file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Let's say I have cards.js file like that

```js
$('.user_hoverable').mouseenter(function() {
    // Get user id from card_data-uid attribute
    let uid = $(this).attr('card_data-uid');
    console.log(`User ${uid} hovered`);
});
```

Then I import it in my html file and set up everything needed

```html
<script src='./card.js'></script>
<div class="user_hoverable card-box" card_data-uid='221'></div>
```

But it doesn't work, I tried putting it in target html file itself and it worked even though elements were dynamically created.
I also tried waiting until page was loaded in card.js file but it didn't work as well.

I also want to add that elements are dynamically created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want event handlers to trigger on elements that are added *after* you have attached the event handler you have to use the "delegated event handler" variant of `jQuery.on()` . You do this by specifying the `selector` parameter of jQuery.on() see https://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$( document ).on( {
    "mouseenter": function() { /* your mouseenter event handler */}
  },
  ".user_hoverable" );
```

Here we have attached the event handler to `document`, but you could also chose any parent element of your `.user_hoverable` elements.

That may also solve your first issue, likely caused by timing of event handler attachment vs the inclusion of your `<div>` in the DOM.